# How to send value of variable from one file to another?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have got A.jsp file in which i have int variable. Now I want to use value of this variable in B.jsp and C.jsp files. How we can do it?

*Edit: So in A.jsp we can declare`request.getSession().setAttribute("nameOfVariable", variable);`* and in B.jsp we can declare `request.getSession().getAttribute("nameOfVariable");`

Comment: Add the value to a query string, add it to some page state for a form post, add it to some server-side session state, add it to a cookie, write it to a storage medium, etc., etc.  There are many ways by which a value created by one page in a web application may be provided to another page.

Comment: Is it not possible to make it a public field in your class? And keep them in the same package?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`RequestDispatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) method and get the attributes :

```
request.setAttribute("list", fooList);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```